# full text search vista

Tags: sql-server-2008

how does one enable full text search for sql server 2008 express in windows vista ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the version of SQL Server Express which *supports* full text search? It's one of the options when you choose which edition to install.

From the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/) description of SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services:

- SQL Server database engine - create, store, update and retrieve your data
- SQL Server Management Studio Basic - visual database management tool for creating, editing and managing databases
- Full-text Search - powerful, high-speed engine for searching text-intensive data
- Reporting Services - integrated report creation and design environment to create reports

So if you didn't install the "Advanced Services" version, I suggest you do so now. I expect you can upgrade from the "standard" version though.